# hibernate: session.load

Tags: java, hibernate, pojo

I'm learning hibernate. To make a tests I invoked `session.load` with invalid key. After I step over that line in debugger (JB Idea), nothing happen - I expected to get ObjectNotFoundException. Than, I opened Expression Eval (alt+F8) and result was:

```
bookFailedLoad = {rs.hibernateTest.model.Book$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5dd17391@2088}Method threw 'org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException' exception. Cannot evaluate rs.hibernateTest.model.Book$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5dd17391.toString()
CGLIB$BOUND = true
CGLIB$CONSTRUCTED = true
CGLIB$CALLBACK_0 = {org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer@2094}
CGLIB$CALLBACK_1 = null
isbn = null
name = null
publisher = null
publishDate = null
price = 0
chapters = null
```

How did hb inform POJO that object is not valid. Please, could someone recommend me an article to help me understand what's happening under the hood before I stock in adventure of debugging hibernate source.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let the debugger run.  `load` throws an exception if the entity is not found.  If you look in the material you pasted, you see

```
Method threw 'org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException' exception. Cannot evaluate rs.hibernateTest.model.Book$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5dd17391.toString()
```

on the first line.

As far as resources are concerned, the Hibernate in Action books is one of the best books I have ever bought.  Well worth it if you are going to spend a lot of time with hibernate.  Just make sure the version of the book you get is relevant to the version of hibernate you are using.

Comment: if I comment log.info line there is no exception thrown:\n log.info("bookFailedGet - " + bookFailedGet);\n Book bookFailedLoad = (Book)session.load(Book.class, "PBN456@");\n // log.info("bookFailedLoad - " + bookFailedLoad);\n \n} catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) { \n log.error("Failed to load book", e); \n \n } catch (Exception e) { \n e.printStackTrace(); \n } finally {